# Do Hong Kong highschool teachers earn more than Hong Kong quants?

Tags: finance, wages, teaching

According to [Teach in Hong Kong](http://www.teachanywhere.com/job-seeker/far-east-asia/hong-kong/), Hong Kong highschool teachers earn around

> HK\$23,530 to HK\$54,665 (approximately \$3,000-\$7,000 USD) per month

while [CUHK's Quantitative Finance Graduates Face Encouraging Employment Status (2004)](http://www.cuhk.edu.hk/cpr/pressrelease/040831e.htm) says Hong Kong quants, at least those who are fresh graduates, have an initial

> average monthly salary of HK$13,291.

Is there anything suspicious about this? I would expect quants to earn more than highschool teachers. Then again, the figure for quants is for fresh grads while the figure for highschool teachers is for those who have at least 2 years teaching experience and with education degrees (eg PGDE).

Comment: 1. Probably not the right SE to ask this question, perhaps Personal Finance or Worklife. 2. As you said it doesn’t make sense to compare entry level finance jobs with non-entry level normal jobs. Salary increase in finance is usually quite large - also many have bonus schemes, which many statistics leave out of the “average salary”. Over time definitely the Quant will make more than the school teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it doesn’t make sense to compare entry level finance jobs with non-entry level normal jobs. Salary increase in finance is usually quite large - also many have bonus schemes, which many statistics leave out of the “average salary”. Over time definitely the Quant will make more than the school teacher.